# Is this a bug in the flag history?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flag-history

Yesterday, I flagged an answer because it was basically just a

> see code here github.com/somerepo
> see video there youtube.com/somevideo

After my comment about the answer being link only, the answerer edited the answer and added the how-to contained in the repository in the answer itself, just leaving the repository and YouTube link at the end of the answer, so I self-removed my original flag.

Then something else did catch my attention and I decided to raise a custom flag on this answer, still.

The feedback in my flag history seems quite off, as it has both the "pending" indicator as well as the old indication that the flag was "Not an answer / self-removed", but with no indication that the current flag I am raising is a custom one.

---

Here is a print screen of the oddity:

[image: Odd flag history feedback]

---

Is this a purposed behaviour or a bug?

Comment: The stuff to the left of your name is the flag reason. You raised 2 flags on the post, and both are shown: the NAA at the bottom, and the custom reason (and its long text) at the top.

Comment: Oh, so the two flags are merged there because they rely on the same answer? Ok, I guess I didn't double flagged enough posts and never observed this behaviour before

Comment: This isn't a bug, try flagging something as spam, then removing it. You will get the self-removed thing. Then if you raise another flag, it will be above the self-removed flag with it's status.

Comment: A note about Not An Answer: It is taken very literally. Wrong answers are still answers. A complete dumpster fire of an answer that will make the question's asker, along with anyone else that reads it, stupider is still an answer. Pretty much anything that can be remotely construed as an attempt to answer is an answer. It can be tricky to get an NAA flag accepted as helpful.

Comment: Never had this impression, still, most of my flags are NAAs.

Comment: Because you probably only flag link-only posts which are valid NAA...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was mentioned already in the comments, this is not a bug. You raised **two different flags** on that post. One flag (the custom one, where you wrote a bunch of text as a message to the moderator) is still pending; the other one ("Not an answer") was "self-removed".

The flag history page is grouped by post. Underneath each post are the flags you have raised on that post. You might have raised one or more flags on each post. Following your flag message is your user name, the timestamp, and the status/resolution of that flag:

[image: Seekrit flag history page decoder ring.]